# batch file with 3 options continually only opens option 1

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

got the below piece of code and having an issue.

i have 3 .bat files i want to open depending on if the user enters 1,2 or 3 
Problem is that it always opens option 1 ..any help is much appreciated

```
@echo off
:start
Color 8A
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ----------------------------------------------------------
echo options:
echo (1) Create 4 Batch Files in 5mb,10mb,15mb,20mb of any type 
echo (2) Create 1 file of a specific size and type
echo (3) Auto Generate a Password
echo -----------------------------------------------------------
set /p __options= Select an option:
if '%_options%'=='1' goto opt1
if '%_options%'=='2' goto opt2
if '%_options%'=='3' goto opt3
ECHO.
:opt1
call "Create 4 File Sizes.bat"
goto end
:opt2
call "Sparse File Creation.bat"
goto end
:opt3
call "Password Generator.bat"
goto end
:end
pause
exit
```

Comment: Additionally to the accepted answer add `goto start` after the last `if` statement, or the script will proceed with option 1 on wrong input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove one of the underscores from:

```
set /p __options= Select an option:
```

to this:

```
set /p _options= Select an option:
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is `__options` but your test is against `_options`.

Also, you may need to handle the case where the input is not 1, 2, nor 3: any other entry will fall through to "opt1," which is actually what was happening in your description, since the variable being tested was not set.

Comment: you mean change it to say optA optB optC ?

Comment: No. I mean: if I enter "4", none of the three `if` statements will evaluate to "true," which means it will arrive at the `:opt1` code block, execute the `call` and then jump to `:end`. So if you don't want invalid entries to simply execute the `call` in `:opt1` you will need to put a `goto end` immediately before `:opt1`.